# how to convert simple string cpp variable to MIPS code

Tags: c++, mips, mips32

Sounds simple, but I have been searching for a good hour or so now.

I want to know if there is a way for me to start a register with a string without having to store the string in .data.

For example, I can do; `li $t0, 0` which has the effect of setting $t0 = 0. This is the same as me saying int a = 0 in cpp.

However, is there a similar way for me to convert `std::string a = "Hello"` to MIPS?

Currently I can do something like this

```
.data
mes: .asciiz "Hello" #declares 'mes' as "Hello"

.text
la $t0, mes #sets $t0 equals to the content of 'mes'
```

but I wish I could skip the first step by doing something like
`sc $t0, "Hello" #set $t0 to characters "Hello" (note: this is not valid MIPS)`

Comment: `std::string` is not a trivial conversion. Why not compile it and see what assembly output you get?

Comment: Obviously the string `"Hello"` wouldn't fit in `$t0` (assuming ASCII encoding), since `$t0` is a 32-bit (4 byte) register.

Comment: It's assembly language.  Everything is done with labels.  Get used to making up label names!  If you want to simplify, then omit those comments that state the obvious, ar ar ;)  Oh- and that `la` sets `$t0` equal to the memory address given to `mes`, not the content of `mes` (quite different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is nothing but a pointer to a byte/char that ends at 0 value byte.
Since there is no native c++ to MIPS compiler we could argue with common sense that the simplest way to define and initialize a string in MIPS is

```
.data
mes: .asciiz "Hello"

.text
la $t0, mes
```